# Why do my badges change from beta to meta, but not my rep?

Tags: support, badges, meta

I see at the top of the meta page that my rep doesn't change when I switch views from the main beta site to its meta site.  But the badges do change.  Is there a reason why the badges are not made to "stick" to me like the rep, between beta and meta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different badges for main and meta, but [rep is for main only](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/507/do-i-get-any-reputation-from-being-upvoted-accepted-on-meta/515#515).