# Do I get any reputation from being upvoted/accepted on meta?

Tags: support, reputation, meta

I didn't see any change in rep when I got upvoted on meta; how does the system work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you don't earn rep on meta. Your rep on meta is synced to B&CG rep each hour and so reflects the rep you've earned there.

Comment: More correctly, you don't earn rep on meta.  Your rep here is synced to b&cg rep each hour.